# get from .net webservice's xml display to android device

Tags: android, .net, web-services

Here is my .net basic webservice

```
[WebMethod]
public bool firstService(string ad)
{
    bool returnValue;
    if (name== "john")
    {
        returnValue = true;
    }
    else
    {
        returnValue = false;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

I want to send a passive parameter with a button help (in my example this is name ) from my android application to .net webservice. And I just want to display returned XML file on my device. How can i do this with using SOAP? (I only want display to XML file not even doing parsing XML :) ) Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create saop message and invoke it. Check out this
http://aaarkonusurum.blogspot.com/2011/10/3-party-kutuphane-kullanmadan-ksoap2.html